# How to determine if a property is being called from the IDE (watch, immediate window etc.) in .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, properties

Is it possible to determine whether a call to a property is from the IDE i.e., from the watch windows, immediate window etc., rather than a normal call from code?

```
Public ReadOnly Property Foo() As Object
  Get
    If CalledFromIDE Then
      'Do something
    Else
      'Do something different
    End If
  End Get
End Property
```

My first thought was to check the stack trace but the IDE seemingly hooks directly into the property without adding anything on the stack.

EDIT

As for the reasoning behind the question, I'm attempting to write some automated WinForms tests using the MS Coded UI framework but the debugging experience is a nightmare. The properties exposed by the UI Test objects continually timeout (causing the debugger to detach) and some crash the debugger entirely. Thus I'm employing a similar approach as described [here](http://o.oz-code.com/debugging-coded-ui-tests-the-horror-and-the-ecstasy) in that I've written a wrapper around the MS objects (hiding its properties) and instead I evaluate the properties in a separate thread with a timeout (blacklisting any properties that fail to evaluate). The successful properties are then exposed in the wrapper.

This improves the debugging experience immensely but when the properties are called in a non-debugging situation, I would like them to be evaluated normally (i.e., without timeouts).

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A property should be implemented in such a way that it doesn't matter if it's called from the IDE or not. Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve as there is almost certainly a better way. For example, if you wanted different debugging information you could consider using the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If the property is a property of a Component/Control you can use the DesignMode (WinForms) or Application.Current.ExecutingStatus == ExecutingStatus.DesignMode (in WPF)

Comment: @RB You are correct about this being an XY problem. I don't need to  determine whether a property its being called from the debugger from _within_ the function. I can instead create a class that encapsulates a property that itself exposes a "debugger" value and a "normal" value. The class will be decorated with the DebuggerDisplayAttribute to ensure the "debugger" value is then one displayed when debugging and normal consumers of the property can select the "normal" value.